# Realizar efecto Audio Fade in/out sobre el canal de Audio en Android

Tags: java, android, audio-manager

Uso las funcion `AudioManager.setStreamMute(..,true/false)` para hacer `mute` o `unmute` al canal de Audio. Evidentemente corta el sonido de golpe, me gustaría que el corte no fuese tan brusco, sino que antes de silenciar se vaya bajando el volumen `sound fadeOut` y al quitar el silencio pues que vaya subiendo como estaba `sound FadeIn`.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que en vez de `setStreamMute()`(el cual esta deprecado a partir de la API 23) podrías utilizar `setStreamVolume (int streamType,int index,int flags)` dentro de un `for` con un pequeño `Timer` para que no sea tan instantaneo. [Aquí la docu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int))

Perdona que no ponga un código de ejemplo, pero no tengo editor de android por aquí

Comment: Buenas, si mas o menos es lo que he pensado hacer un bucle N segundos y vaya bajando el volumen. La cosa está en no saturar el proceso y que sea cada 100ms mas o menos. voy a investigar más.

Comment: Lo suyo seria hacerlo dentro de un `AsyncTask` o similar, para evitar como dices bloquear el hilo prinicpal.